# Drupal multi step User Edit profile in light box

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-forms

Im newbuy to drupal and really curious to work more , And i created a content type for profile and link it with edit profile through content profile and make it as multi step using multistep module .

But i wish to make the form in the light box through custom with themeing process.

Anyone please guide how to render the form or any clue.

Thanks,
Nithish

Comment: I'm not a themer, but this seems like an awful lot of unnecessary work when upgrading to Drupal 7 would get you overlay in core.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ajax tools in [ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools), or the [dialog api](http://drupal.org/project/dialog) which is built on top of them, or use it for inspiration. What you are trying to accomplish is not a novice task, but definately doable.